# Outlook showing invisble drafts

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook-2016

In Outlook 2016, when I connect to my email account, it is showing a lot of "drafts" that don't exist in the `Bezvrijedna e-pošta` folder:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there any fix regarding the issue?

Comment: Do you see the same number while connected to Outlook online?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that there are not 102 emails in your Junk folder although it shows [102] ? Can this issue be reproduced on your web mail?

Please right click your Junk folder > Properties > Select "Show number of unread items" > Apply > OK then see if there is any difference.

[image]